# Cannot trigger touch event programmatically in a web view on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm trying to programmatically simulate a touch event in Flutter and it works on buttons and any other tappable widgets, however it is not working inside a web view (on websites) on iOS.

Below you can find a minimal reproducible example, only the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/install) package needs to be added in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

In the example below, there is a draggable hand icon which works similarly to a mouse pointer: when you press the red floating action button, it fires a touch event on the icon's position. In case of Android, buttons and links can be clicked on any website, but on iOS nothing can be clicked (I've tried in simulator and on real device).

Any help or suggestion on why it's not working on iOS is much appreciated.

[image: example]

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'InAppWebView Issue',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'InAppWebView Issue'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late double x = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
  late double y = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;
  late final appBar = AppBar(title: Text(widget.title));
  late final appBarAndStatusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top + appBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://www.willyoupressthebutton.com/")),
              initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                  javaScriptEnabled: true,
                  preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.MOBILE,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            /// draggable pointer icon:
            Positioned(
              left: x,
              top: y,
              child: Draggable(
                feedback: tapIcon(),
                childWhenDragging: Container(),
                onDragEnd: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    x = details.offset.dx;
                    y = details.offset.dy - appBarAndStatusBarHeight;
                  });
                },
                child: tapIcon(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(
            PointerDownEvent(
              position: Offset(x, y + appBarAndStatusBarHeight - 1),
              radiusMin: 20,
              radiusMax: 50,
            ),
          );
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
          GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(
            PointerUpEvent(
              position: Offset(x, y + appBarAndStatusBarHeight - 1),
              radiusMin: 20,
              radiusMax: 50,
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Text("PRESS"),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget tapIcon() {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      child: const Icon(Icons.touch_app, size: 40),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any luck for this issue?